# Получить массив объектов из JSON Jackson

Tags: java, json, java-8, jackson

Всем привет!
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с Jackson парсером из JSON:
Сам JSON:

```
    {
    "person": [
      {"name": "Jon Doye"},
      {"name": "Joahna Doye"}
    ]
  }
```

Мои классы:

Класс PersonList:

```
public class PersonList {
    List<Person> person;

    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(List<Person> person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}
```

Класс Person:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Так же парсер:

```
public static InputData readJsonFile(String path){
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), UTF_8))){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while(br.read() > -1){
               stringBuilder.append(br.readLine());
            }
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            PersonList personList = objectMapper.readValue(stringBuilder.toString(), PersonList.class);
            System.out.println(personList);
       ...
    }
```

При компиляции возвращает ошибку:

```
Cannot construct instance of `domain.input.testdata.PersonList` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('person')
 at [Source: (String)"   "person": [     {"name": "Jon Doye"},     {"name": "Joahna Doye"}   ] } "; line: 1, column: 4]
```

При этом JSON в формате:

```
{[
  {"name": "Jon Doye"},
  {"name": "Joahna Doye"}
]}
```

Будет работать нормально с кодом:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Person> personList = objectMapper.readValue(stringBuilder.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {});
System.out.println(personList);
```

Наведите пожалуйста на мысль, что делаю не так?

Comment: Второй json [не является валидным](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator/y227b97fc).

Comment: `br.read()` считывает один символ, а `br.readLine()` считывает оставшуюся часть строки (без первого символа), так вы теряете по одному символу в каждой строке, зачем вам такая логика? предлагаю удалить этот участок кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите странный код со `StringBuilder` и передайте `BufferedReader br` напрямую в метод `readValue()`:

```java
PersonList personList = objectMapper.readValue(br, PersonList.class);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Помогло после удаления секции while. Видимо BufferedReader можно прочитать только 1 раз.  Поправьте пожалуйста, если это не так :^)

Comment: Да, если нужно прочитать второй раз, то нужно заново открывать BufferedReader, либо пользоваться методами [mark и reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240545).

Comment: Если этот ответ вам помог, то вы можете принять его, нажав на галочку слева.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Более внимательно изучу работу BufferedReader.